# Adding Google Invisible Recaptcha in Ajax Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

This is my code ajax form code **without** installing Google Invisible Recaptcha

```js
$("form.formajax").click(function()
{
var form = $(this);
console.log(form);

    //AJAX code to submit form.
    $.ajax(
    {
      type: "POST",
      url: $(this).attr("action"),
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      cache: false,
      success: function(data)
      {
        $(form).children(".signupresult").html(data.signupresult);
        $(form).children(".signupresult").css("opacity", "1");
        $(form).children(".signupresult").css("background-color", data.backgroundcolor);

        $(form).children(".loginresult").html(data.loginresult);
        $(form).children(".loginresult").css("opacity", "1");

        $(".forgotpassresult").html(data.forgotpassresult);
        $(".forgotpassresult").css("opacity", "1");
        $(".forgotpassresult").css("background-color", data.backgroundcolor);

        if (data.success == 1) 
        {
        window.location = "profile.php";
        }


      }

    });

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="loginform formajax" method="post" action="admin/login/logincheck.php">
    <input id="submit" type="text">
</form> 

<form class="loginform formajax" method="post" action="admin/login/logincheck.php">
    <input id="submit" type="text">
</form>
```

Now, this is my code after adding Google Invisible Recaptcha

```js
var onloadCallback = function() {
    $( "#submit" ).each(function() {
        grecaptcha.render($( this ).attr('id'), {
            'sitekey' : '6Lcjvi4UAAAAAIR7_ckItF2HfMEFHx427WUDdGDk',
            'callback' : onsubmit
        });
    });
};







var onsubmit = function(token) 
{
  $(document).ready(function()
  {  
    $("form.formajax").click(function()
    {
    var form = $(this);
    console.log(form);

        //AJAX code to submit form.
        $.ajax(
        {
          type: "POST",
          url: $(this).attr("action"),
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          cache: false,
          success: function(data)
          {
            $(form).children(".signupresult").html(data.signupresult);
            $(form).children(".signupresult").css("opacity", "1");
            $(form).children(".signupresult").css("background-color", data.backgroundcolor);

            $(form).children(".loginresult").html(data.loginresult);
            $(form).children(".loginresult").css("opacity", "1");

            $(".forgotpassresult").html(data.forgotpassresult);
            $(".forgotpassresult").css("opacity", "1");
            $(".forgotpassresult").css("background-color", data.backgroundcolor);

            if (data.success == 1) 
            {
            window.location = "profile.php";
            }


          }

        });

      return false;
    });


  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="loginform formajax" method="post" action="admin/login/logincheck.php">
    <input id="submit" type="text">
</form> 

<form class="loginform formajax" method="post" action="admin/login/logincheck.php">
    <input id="submit" type="text">
</form>
```

**Problem:**

The form do not get submitted after Google Recaptcha Verfication.

This is what happens:

User Clicks on Submit Button > User gets google recaptcha window > User answers the question > submit the recaptcha > verified > recaptcha window closes > form do not get submitted.

The form is supposed to get submitted as soon as the recaptcha window closes after getting verified.

But after the window closes, the user needs to click on the form submit button again (total two times).

How to make the form get submitted after google verify the user is not a bot.

Comment: hahah thirrt time you are posting this one :P

Comment: @Aaron can u talk to me here, please? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/64948/hey-aaron?tab=general